# Web application storage with huge variation

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have just installed Wordpress in a new Azure Web Application and everything is running fine at the moment.

However, I am getting notifications that I am exceeding the storage file system quota (1GB).

I went to check the value on the Azure Portal and the strange thing is that the storage usage is varying from 12% to 100% every single minute! Somehow the measurement must be crazy, since I am not changing a bit in my website nor have huge files there.

12% must be the realistic value for Wordpress. I have tried to reset the website and check log files to see if there is anything wrong, but did not find anything.

How can I fix that?

Igor.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try de-activating the most recent plugins you installed 1 by 1 to see if this corrects the issue. There could be a bug in one of them that has some type of loop that generates a large log file.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the same day the problem disappeared. It seems everything is stable now, but if happened once, it might happen again. I will keep you posted in case I experience this problem again.
Thank you.